# Resize colorbox overlay to fit into a div instead of the screen width

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to build a colorbox gallery which should be resized leaving a fixed-widht column in the left side.
My column is 250px width, so I changed the CSS and tried to change the colorbox settings in Jquery, but it works partially.

This is my test site: https://www.cesarecrova.it/wordpress02/
the colorbox start with a orange background.

I changed these lines in jquery.colorbox.js:

```
function setSize(size, dimension) {
    return Math.round((/%/.test(size) ? ((dimension === 'x' ? $window.width() : winheight()) / 100) : 1) * parseInt(size, 10));
}
```

Into:

```
function setSize(size, dimension) {
    return Math.round((/%/.test(size) ? ((dimension === 'x' ? ($window.width() - 250) : winheight()) / 100) : 1) * parseInt(size, 10));
}
```

"250" is the fixed width for the column.

The picture is resized to the screen.
I would like that the picture is proportionally resized into the orange div.

N.B in this test site the issue appears expecially when the screen size is smaller than 800px;

I think the solution should be simple, but I'm not skilled with Jquery and JS....
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOlved.

I ad the column width to this initial setting sizes:

```
// Opens inital empty Colorbox prior to content being loaded.
            var initialWidth = setSize(settings.get('initialWidth' - 250), 'x');
            var initialHeight = setSize(settings.get('initialHeight'), 'y');
            var maxWidth = settings.get('maxWidth');
            var maxHeight = settings.get('maxHeight');
```

May this be helpful..